# still getting alb cookies even though stickiness is disabled on the target when alb is origin for cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

I am still getting "AWSALB" and "AWSALBCORS" cookies when interacting with my website via Cloudfront even though I have disabled stickiness on the target group.

I have tested the application load balancer without Cloudfront and I do not get the cookies however, when I test the exact same site with the distribution in front of the application load balancer, I receive the cookies .

My cloudfront distribution has been configured to forward cookies and query strings to the origin via a request policy. I am not trying to cache based on cookies.

How do I resolve this as I need to use Cloudfront?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I am facing a similar issue where I do not want any of these cookie to be set by our load balancer

Comment: @JFoley those cookies are set for session affinity , i.e sticky sessions. So , if you have a stateless application , you don't need this sort of behaviour , you can then update your target group on to remove session stickiness.

However, i think it was like a propagation problem ... I can't really remember , I'm not a fan of using cloudfront infront of  webservers with sessions and that.